# Show templates from different components on same place

Tags: angular

I am trying to rewrite the administration of application to Angular2. I have 3 components (AppComponent, SystemComponent and ShopComponent).

**AppComponent:**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {SystemComponent} from "./system.component";

@Component({
   selector: 'app',
   templateUrl: '/templates/layout',
   directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
   {
       path: '/',
       redirectTo: ['/System'],
       useAsDefault: true
   },
   {
       path: '/-1/...',
       name: 'System',
       component: SystemComponent
   }
])
export class AppComponent {
   constructor(router: Router){
       router.navigate(['/System']);
   }
}
```

**SystemComponent:**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, RouterOutlet} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
   directives: [RouterOutlet]
})
export class SystemComponent {}
```

**ShopComponent:**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, RouterOutlet} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
   directives: [RouterOutlet]
})
export class ShopComponent {}
```

I need to modify SystemComponent and ShopComponent, to load a different template in two different places with different design and content (In detail in FIG.)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you need for the real implementation, but for this scenario you don't have to change the templates of the component, you just have to serve a different component to different routes. Create a `<router-outlet>` in your main `AppComponent` component, and configure three different routes on it, one handles `/system` with something like `IndexComponent` instead of `AppComponent`, another handles `/system/-1` to `SystemComponent` and the third handles `/system/2` to `ShopComponent`.

Comment: Another way is to wire up the base layout in `AppComponent` and server children routes marking the route as `/system/...` which would point to another Routing Component that handles `/-1` and `/2` routes to its respective Component into its own  `<router-outlet>`.

Comment: @Langley It's a good idea, but I have 2 menu, so I had to have a two router-outlets (one for left menu and second for top menu).

Comment: Just parse them each inside your other components, each component can have its own template, you are supposed to navigate between components, reuse them or switch them, not change their templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't dynamically change templateUrl of Component. One component == one html page.

What you can do is to use control flow, for example ***ngIf** or ***ngSwitch** to load different portion of template based on some criteria.

Comment: I don't want to change the dynamic templateUrl. Rather, I need to use 2 templateUrl simultaneously.

Comment: That is not possible. You can create two child components instead, and use DCL ( Dynamic Component Loader ) to inject on of them, again, based on some criteria.

Comment: Can I use the components instead of templates in highlighted areas? In this case it would be one main component and four subcomponents.

Comment: In my eyes, you need one main component, for example AppComponent, in template of that component you would have placement for #topBar and #leftBar . In router you will have three routes, /system resolve to AppComponent, /system/-1 with RoutData https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouteData-class.html ( System ) and thrid /system/2 with route data Shop... Than, you need to split System and Shop into two components ( top and sidebar ). If you need to share same data between them, you can create Services which you will inject into both components.

Comment: Ok I try. But DCL is probably what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: I found a problem. When using DCL can set variables in the template: X

Comment: Yes, there is no binding anymore ( and two way binding ) in created components.

Comment: Is there any solution to get variables to dynamically loaded components?

Comment: Currently no. Can you call services from those components ( without passing data )?